# How to link two models, each with its own template using foreignKey in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to link two models using foreignKey, The problem is when i try to do that, one model does not get foreignKey value for the next model in the database table.
The aim is for user to fill information on the first page (have its own model and template) then click next (fill more info in the next page having its own model and template) then click next for the same logic. then when other users view this post it must show all content from different models in one page. here is my code.

1st model

```
class Map(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 position = GeopositionField()
```

HAVING ITS OWN TEMPLATE

2nd Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
 parent = models.ForeignKey("self", default=None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 content = models.TextField()

 map = models.ForeignKey(Map, related_name='mapkey', default=None,  blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

HAVING ITS OWN TEMPLATE BUT also has serializer method(API) below:

```
class PostModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 user = UserDisplaySerializer(read_only=True)
 parent = ParentPostModelSerializer()

 map = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

 class Meta:
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget())
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget())
    model = Post
    fields = [
        'id',
        'user',
        'title',
        'content'
        'image',

        'map',

    ]
```

Please focus only on the map field as its isolated in the above codes
everything works perfectly, but the foreignKey. also i didnt see the need to include all the code here but snippets.

i have been struggling with this for days now. do i need to write an api for 1st model also? for views i used class based views.

the database table for model 2, on the map field it shows null all the time.
I have i have provided enough information.Thanks

Comment: How are you creating a `Post`? Are you making a request to the API to do that, or is that done via a form post from a template?

Comment: via form, which creates an api.. then show api data to the view(page). i just dont know how to go about this.